# How do I delete work item areas in Team Foundation Server 2012?

Tags: tfs, agile, alm

I am considering moving from FogBugz to TFS 2012 for our bug/defect tracking.  In FogBugz it's easy to create areas such as Database, Reports, etc.  I went to the work items area and it had one that matched the project name.  I created children of that to match our different teams.  I later decided to add teams in TFS (I'm new to TFS, a lot to figure out!) so it created work areas to match the teams.  So now I have:

```
ProjectName
--Blah
--Blah Team
--Foo
--Foo Team
```

Now I want to go back and delete Blah and Foo because it is foolish and confusing the way it is now.

How can I delete these work item areas I no longer want?

Thank you.

Comment: I just found it right after posting!  You can right-click on the items and there is the delete option.  Duh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to team web access then right-click the items you no longer want and a context menu will appear with options such as delete.